# Django FieldError when trying to delete User

Tags: python, django, exception, model, relationship

I'm having problems deleting a user (just for tests), and I'm not sure what's going on. I'm running python 3.6 and Django 1.11.6. My tests don't use database migrations, they create the database directly from the model, but the same happens when I try to delete an existing entry from the normal, correctly migrated database.

First I create a user:

```
user = User.objects.create_user('testing', 'testing@test.com', 'testpass')
```

And the I just call:

```
user.delete()
```

And it crashes inside the delete() method. The user doesn't even need to have a related UserImage added, and it still crashes. Initially I thought that it's caused by the related object, as the exception says "join on 'added' is not permitted", and 'added' is a field on UserImage. Any help is appreciated as I'm looking at it for hours and can't find the cause :(

---

models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Username must be set.')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
    USERNAME_ALLOWED_REGEX = r'\w._-'

    objects = UserManager()

    username = models.CharField(
        db_index=True,
        max_length=10, unique=True,
        help_text=_('10 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and ._- only.'),
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(r'^[' + USERNAME_ALLOWED_REGEX + r']+$', _('Enter a valid username.'), 'invalid')
        ],
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=30, blank=True,
        help_text=_('Maximum 30 characters.'),
    )

    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=30, blank=True,
        help_text=_('Maximum 30 characters.'),
    )

    email = models.EmailField(
        unique=True,
    )

    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        default=True,
    )

    joined = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, editable=False,
    )

    avatar = models.OneToOneField(
        'UserImage',
        null=True, blank=True, related_name='avatar_user',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        )

    def add_image(self, name, content, save=True):
        new_image = UserImage(user=self)
        new_image.save_images(name, content, save=save)

        return new_image

class UserImage(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user_image')
        verbose_name_plural = _('user_images')
        ordering = 'id',

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='images',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    added = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, editable=False,
    )

    image = RenamedProcessedImageField(
        upload_to=user_image_path,
        processors=(ResizeToFit(2048, 2048, upscale=False),),
        format='JPEG',
        options={'quality': 100},
        )

    def save_images(self, name, content, save=True):
        self.image.save(name, content, save=False)

        if save:
            self.full_clean(validate_unique=False)
            self.save()
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***/users/tests.py", line 237, in test_files_on_delete_rule
    user.delete()
  File "***/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 973, in delete
    collector.collect([self], keep_parents=keep_parents)
  File "***/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 222, in collect
    elif sub_objs:
  File "***/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 254, in __bool__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "***/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "***/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "***/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 871, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "***/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 423, in as_sql
    extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
  File "***/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 47, in pre_sql_setup
    order_by = self.get_order_by()
  File "***/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 298, in get_order_by
    field, self.query.get_meta(), default_order=asc))
  File "***/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 601, in find_ordering_name
    field, targets, alias, joins, path, opts = self._setup_joins(pieces, opts, alias)
  File "***/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 634, in _setup_joins
    pieces, opts, alias)
  File "***/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1417, in setup_joins
    names, opts, allow_many, fail_on_missing=True)
  File "***/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1385, in names_to_path
    " not permitted." % (names[pos + 1], name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'max' into field. Join on 'added' not permitted.
```

Comment: You have completed all migrations? If you tried testing removing the FK of user image completely, would it work then?

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, I also tried it after doing the migrations from scratch. I just tried that, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Im a lot closer to the issue right now, I tried deleting all model relationships to the User class, and it worked, so I was putting them back and trying to find which is causing the issue, and found out it's actually my forum models causing it, and I probably even know why.

Comment: I have User, Topic, Post. Topic has ForeignKey to User (on_delete CASCADE), and Post has ForeignKey to both Topic (on_delete CASCADE) and User (on_delete CASCADE). So it seems like I have to change the User on_delete rule so that it doesn't collide with the Topic one :)

Comment: Not sure what I should set the second rule to, though, as DO_NOTHING causes the same issue.

Comment: Why does topic have a foreign key to user? Would it work if you removed that constraint?

Comment: Yes, it does, but I need this key because the post can also have other user than the parent topic has in it's relationship.

Comment: Duplicate of [Django duplicate ON\_DELETE rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46860477/django-duplicate-on-delete-rule).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found out the issue was actually caused by the ordering definition on my Topic model:

```
class ForumTopic(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = '-forum_posts__added__max',
```

It works when I remove it, or change it to:

```
class ForumTopic(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = '-id',
```